# Source video tag does not work.HTML

Tags: html, magento

I have this page:

[link](http://www.moment-of-style.com/special-projects)

I want to add a video of my own and I use this source code

```
<p><video id="sampleMovie" width="320" height="240" src="wysiwyg/movie.avi" controls="controls"></video></p>
```

Unfortunately does not work ... is something wrong in my writing?

[link2](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp)

The site is made with Magento, can this be a problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Console error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

EDIT2:

```
<p><video id="sampleMovie" width="320" height="240" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/movie.avi" controls="controls"></video></p>
```

I changed the video source and the error only appears in the console but still not working video

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error? What does the console show?

Comment: I eddit my post,sorry

Comment: path is incorrect due to this 404 error shown

Comment: yes,I corrected this error

Comment: @cristi Edit your `src` to reflect the actual location of the video. Pro-tip: type it into the location bar to check :-)

Comment: @cristi can you play the video by going to the video src itself? It could be down to the codecs that the browser supports. Easiest option is to upload it to YouTube or Vimeo and let them handle that kinda stuff.

Comment: I put the direct path.Can not you get on youtube because I work for the client does not agree

Comment: So the problem is because the browser is not the codecs?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't support .avi format. Use `H.264 (MPEG-4 AVC), OGG Theora (VP3), WebM (VP8)`. Like this:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

BTW, there shouldn't be any issues between magento cms pages and the video tag (I used it many times).